# Boto3 list_object_v2 painfully slow

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to use the Boto3 API (specifically, list_objects_v2, as this is what's recommended) to get all keys on my buckets. I executed 8 tasks in parallel on each bucket that I have on S3 totaling about ~55Gb of data. I have been running this for 16+ hours and none of my calls have returned. Is this expected behavior? If it even has to download the entire 55Gb it should not take more than a few hours to download at most (I'm on a very fast internet connection).

Is AWS rate limiting me in some abnormal way? Their documentation says there is a limit of 5,500 requests per second. Since I'm looking at the order of ~5,000,000 S3 items, if I am being rate limited by my estimate the rate limiting given an infinitely fast connection shouldn't lower bound my transfer time at more than 15 minutes. So this is not the issue?

As an aside, this operation appears to be monopolizing my CPU. The below code is what I am executing for this call. Is there something blatantly obvious I am missing here? Looks to me that it's spending all of it's time in the call to `list_objects_v2`. I'm no AWS guru so it's possible what I'm doing is super bad for *reasons* I don't know.

```
def list_all_keys(self):
        reached_end = False
        all_keys = []
        token = None
        while not reached_end:
            # will limit to 1000 objects
            response = self.client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=self.bucket)
            token = response.get('NextContinuationToken', None)
            contents = response.get('Contents', [])
            all_keys.extend([obj['Key'] for obj in contents])
            if not token and response.get('IsTruncated') is False:
                reached_end = True
        return all_keys
```

Comment: what about using generator instead of the normal for loop? besides that you can use ```top``` to check cpu and memory usage

Comment: I thought about this - you think it's possible not using generators/pagination is causing a significant slow down? I've been monitoring the CPU/memory usage and each process exhibits consistently high (though not maximum) cpu usage and growing memory usage. My thought behind running a bunch of these all at once was that it would ultimately be faster since this task is I/O bound. Perhaps that line of thinking isn't correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone looking at this, I have actually arrived at an answer. The key is to not use `list_objects_v2` and instead use the S3 resource bucket. This is at least 10x faster on my machine and I guess should always be preferred.

```
bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('bucket-name')
keys = []
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    keys.append(obj.key)
```

Comment: If you didn t find this then I would let you know the `resource`.

Comment: Can you explain why the resource Bucket is more efficiently cost than the list_objects_v2?

Comment: I am not sure if it's more cost efficient, just seemed to perform way better, which is what matters for me.

Answer (score 0):

client is almost always faster and better than resource, except in ease of use. Depending on os or versions, client can turn a 1 hour list_objects to less than 5 minutes. Or both versions will be 5 minutes (with client being being 0.5~1 minute faster). I don't know the circumstances, but my linux version had the issue of resource being 1 hr vs 5 min client. While on windows they were both 5 min. But this could have been due to outdated boto3 library on that linux machine.

Anyways,

The error in your code is that you never used the continuation token, so all calls to list_objects_v2 were calling the same 1000 files over and over again until the end of time, infinitely increasing your list size.

```
def list_all_keys(self):
        reached_end = False
        all_keys = []
        token = None
        first = false
        while not reached_end:
            # will limit to 1000 objects
            if first: 
                response = self.client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=self.bucket)
            else:
                response = self.client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=self.bucket, NextContinuationToken=token)
            token = response.get('NextContinuationToken', None)
            contents = response.get('Contents', [])
            all_keys.extend([obj['Key'] for obj in contents])
            if not token and response.get('IsTruncated') is False:
                reached_end = True
        return all_keys
```